# Union type mapped to an object with single key

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to create an object type with a single key that is one of the strings from the string union type?

Example:

```
type Key = "a" | "b" | "c"

const result = {
  a: "hello there"
}

const result2 = {
  b: "General Kenobi"
}

const result3 = {
  c: 2137
}

// All types above should be correct after mapping

const wrongType = {
  a: "hello there";
  b: "General Kenobi";
}

const wrongType2 = {};

// Those should be wrong because either it's not a single-key object, or it doesn't have keys at all
```

Comment: may I ask more context about what you're trying to reach doing that? depending on other fields, you can do something like a "type guard"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`mapped types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

```
type Keys = "a" | "b" | "c";

type T = {
  [key in Keys]: { [k in key]: unknown } & {
    [k in Exclude<Keys, key>]?: never;
  };
}[Keys];
```

So, we generate a type that is a union of three objects where each object explicitly states that if one property is present others should not be present. So, the generated type is the following:

```
type T =
  | { a: unknown; b?: undefined; c?: undefined }
  | { b: unknown; a?: undefined; c?: undefined }
  | { c: unknown; a?: undefined; b?: undefined };
```

**NOTE**: Just doing the following:

```
type T = {
  [key in Keys]: { [k in key]: unknown }
}[Keys];
```

would **not** work because [Unions without discriminant properties do not perform excess property checking](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863).

Comment: I've [tried](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oCICGaoB90CNs80BjNAKHNElnhSgG8BtAazoEsA7WxAXQC5GrKFyhsQAqBk4gAvrKZw+lAPQqoAeRgBCciQD2nBMCgAnCAgCuAG2CCl9BuShTBaABYRr1-VGCfzCllVdS1dAyMTcytbACZ7OlQnF3w3AHEITghTDGtaTn18diCQzR09Q2MzCxtgAGYEkEdnKBJBWIBGOoB2cmDyNSgAUVNTfVMoABNLaGBfAqgAWwxgEncuAHM-cAgKyKgAdzHODYAVHcbmlww3T29ff2yINAAaFtT0DKycvLgCotefVKAEFrAhfNkxqYEHsqkdDGcdvEeI5gkA) out this one and it doesn't complain about `{ a: 'x', b: 'x' }`

Comment: Yes, thank you it works and as you pointed out correctly additional keys are not a problem

Comment: @wleklinski The earlier solution wasn't correct, it wasn't performing excess property check, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is using the library called [ts-xor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-xor):

```
import { XOR } from 'ts-xor'

let test: <A, B>
type Key = XOR<{ a: string }, XOR<{ b: string }, { c: string }>>

// OK!
const result: Key = {
  a: "hello there"
}

// OK!
const result2: Key = {
  b: "General Kenobi"
}

// OK!
const result3: Key = {
  c: 2137
}

// Error due to no matching type
const wrongType: Key = {
  a: "hello there",
  b: "General Kenobi",
}

// Also errors
const wrongType2: Key = {}
```